# Access to fields in json reactjs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

```
base: "cmc stations"
clouds: {all: 76}
cod: 200
coord: {lon: 13.37, lat: 52.52}
dt: 1456791041
id: 2822234
main: {temp: 0.17, pressure: 1028.91, humidity: 77, temp_min: 0.17, temp_max: 0.17, sea_level: 1035.1,…}
name: "Tiergarten"
sys: {message: 0.003, country: "DE", sunrise: 1456811534, sunset: 1456850772}
weather: [{id: 803, main: "Clouds", description: "broken clouds", icon: "04n"}]
wind: {speed: 5.21, deg: 48.0012}
```

Hi all , please, with this json and reactjs , how to I can access to main temp??

When I write this.props.dates.main.temp I always get undefined , but if I write this.props.dates.name , I have no problem , also when I write this.props.date.weather[0].description the response is undefined.
What is the problem , I have no idea...

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean date/dates/data?  You use date and dates in your description.  I think you should show a little bit more about how you're getting/setting your json data, but that should be your main problem.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, maybe  you are not passing the right data, I did a codepen that is working, try checking it out.

http://codepen.io/philolo1/pen/WwbObQ

```
var Example = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      base: "cmc stations",
    clouds: {all: 76},
    cod: 200,
    coord: {lon: 13.37, lat: 52.52},
    dt: 1456791041,
    id: 2822234,
    main: {temp: 0.17, pressure: 1028.91, humidity: 77, temp_min: 0.17, temp_max: 0.17, sea_level: 1035.1},
    name: "Tiergarten",
    sys: {message: 0.003, country: "DE", sunrise: 1456811534, sunset: 1456850772},
    weather: [{id: 803, main: "Clouds", description: "broken clouds", icon: "04n"}],
    wind: {speed: 5.21, deg: 48.0012}
    }
  },

    styler: {
      width: "100px",
    height: "100px",
    mozBorderRadius: "50%",
    webkitBorderRadius: "50%",
    borderRadius: "50%",
    background: "red"
    },

    render: function() {
      return (
          <div> {this.props.main.temp}</div>
          );
    }
});

React.render(
    <Example />, 
    document.getElementById('mount-point'));
```

Comment: I thought it was better a response to edit the first post.

Answer (score 0):

Well finally I can read the field of json , the solution is , in state , make one property with datos: { main { temp: 0}}
With that , this property have one value in the start.
But really I do not understand what is wrong with that field json.